# Unable to start rails server in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I installed Rails using RVM. Everything works fine like generating a new app with `rails new app`. `bundle install` and every other command runs fine as well.
But when I start my Rails server with `rails -server` I get the following error, which I'm not able to understand.

```
rails aborted!
NameError: undefined local variable or method `rver' for #<Rake::Application:0x00563aa7540988>
/home/mrrobot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:12:in `block in run_rake_task'
/home/mrrobot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:11:in `run_rake_task'
/home/mrrobot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `run_command!'
/home/mrrobot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/home/mrrobot/rails/demo/app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/home/mrrobot/rails/demo/app/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/mrrobot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/home/mrrobot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/home/mrrobot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/home/mrrobot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/home/mrrobot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/spring-2.0.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/home/mrrobot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
/home/mrrobot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
/home/mrrobot/rails/demo/app/bin/spring:15:in `require'
/home/mrrobot/rails/demo/app/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

**Ruby version: 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-linux]**

**Rails version: 5.0.2**

**RubyGems version: 2.6.11**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `rails server`, without dash

or just

```
rails s
```

Comment: Yes it worked, I wonder however what does the following command does "rails -server"

Comment: There is no `-server` option

Comment: The error was not quiet descriptive about the command being incorrect.

Comment: If you run `rails --help` you can see all the available options